# Keep a Java object alive for the duration of a session

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

In my JSP application, I want to keep track of the user that's logged in.

When the user tries to log in, I use database transactions in a `UserManager` class to verify that the entry exists (I'm not aiming to make a very secure site, most of this is for learning).

That `UserManager` class constructs a `User` instance object out of the retrieved information on the user (i.e. their name, age, photo, etc).

I use this object to efficiently call prepare the presentation on the user's home page, after the log in is successful.

The trouble is, I don't know how to keep this `User` object alive for the duration of the whole session with the user. For example, if he goes to other pages, I still want to be able to call

```
user.getPhoto()
```

or

```
user.getLastName()
```

without complicated database queries each time.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using any framework or only servlets ?

Comment: No framework. Just Servlets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the object in session. Inside your servlet, just call this:

```
User user = ... //use your UserManager or something else to get the user
if (<valid user>) {
    //store the user object in session
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
}
//forward to the next view...
```

Then you can retrieve the data in your view (JSP, Facelets) using Expression Language:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- tags... -->
    <div>
        Welcome ${user.name}
        <!-- ${user.name} will call session.getAttribute("user").getName() for you -->
    </div>
</html>
```

More info:

- [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Didn't provide an example using scriptlets because you should not use them. Explanation on link above.

---

Don't forget to clear the session when performing a log out:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```